# Incentive Plan Not Included in Offer Letter

Tags: job-offer

I received an offer letter that under "Compensation and Incentives" only lists the annual salary. It does not list the incentive plan which is up to 35% of annual salary based on specific performance metrics of my group.  I received the incentive plan in a different email. HR indicated they no longer include incentive plan in offer letters. Since they stated "Compensation and Incentives" in the offer letter I feel the incentive plan eligibility (up to 35% of salary) should be included in the offer letter. Appreciate everyone's comments.

Comment: You got them both in writing, but essentially in two documents instead of one?  Are both on letterhead and signed?

Comment: I would not count on getting an incentive in any event whether in the letter or not. Those things change frequently which is likely why they took it out of the offer letter. Never choose a job because of an incentive plan.

Comment: That is correct, received in two separate documents. The job offer is on company letter head but not signed. The incentive plan is for 2017 on company letter head but not signed.  (I am currently a contractor with the company and converting to employee status, and the incentive plan letter was received prior to the job offer and is for 2017 as a contractor or continues the same if I accept job offer as employee. )

Answer (score 5):

> Since they stated "Compensation and Incentives" in the offer letter I
>   feel the incentive plan eligibility (up to 35% of salary) should be
>   included in the offer letter. Appreciate everyone's comments.

You could always insist that they include the incentive plan in the offer letter if you are that uncomfortable. Decide ahead of time what you will do if they refuse (accept anyway? walk away?).

You could also print out the email and have them sign it.

But I doubt any of that is really necessary.

If it were me, I'd save a copy of both the offer letter and the email detailing incentive plan eligibility and feel okay about it.